# string to number conversion in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function having following lines:

```
payementReceived=data.toJSON().total;
paymentTotal=$("#paymentTotal").html();

console.log(typeof(parseInt(paymentTotal)));                  
console.log(typeof(parseInt(paymentReceived)));
console.log(parseInt(paymentTotal)-parseInt(paymentReceived));
```

I get the following in console

```
number
number
NaN
```

i don't understand if both are numbers then why it isn't able to give the proper substraction result.

Comment: `new Number()`, not just `Number()`. Or rather - `parseInt(xxx, 10)`

Comment: `typeof(NaN) === "number"`

Comment: Becaue the `NaN` value is of type `number` as well?

Comment: What are the values of `paymentTotal` and `paymentReceived`?

Comment: this is interesting one, would you mind giving us the actual number that you get for paymentReceived and paymentTotal?

Comment: values are 100 percent numbers. like 750 in payment total and 350 in payment received...

Comment: @beNerd Please give some concrete values, what do you get if you `console.log(paymentTotal)` and `paymentReceived`?

Comment: Note that when you use `parseInt`, you should always include `10` as a second parameter (otherwise numbers starting with a 0 will be read as base 8!)

Comment: is it because of the typo??
"payementReceived" instead of "paymentReceived"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values are `number` in that their contents are a number, but it doesn't mean that the number is valid.

```
typeof NaN === 'number'
```

If you are getting a `NaN` back from your subtraction, one or both of your input values are invalid numbers.

Answer (score 0):

problem is because of the undefined varaible used "paymentReceived" if you are sure that the result is a number you can always use **parseInt**

```
console.log(parseInt(paymentTotal)-parseInt(payementReceived));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a funny idea :

```
if (typeof n === "number" && n+1 !== n) {
    // this is a valid number
}
```

invalid+1 will still be invalid so it could check for invalid numbers.

Answer (score -1):

try below code

console.log(Number(paymentTotal)-Number(payementReceived));